# Rigid foam board expansion

Tags: insulation

I’m installing extruded polystyrene rigid foam board over my exterior sheathing. I got a little behind schedule and now the temps have dropped to the 30s (Fahrenheit). Do I need to allow for the foam to expand in warmer weather? How big of gaps should I leave (if any) on the seams and the edges? I don’t want it to distort my siding when we get back into the 90s next summer.

Comment: Great question. In many years of construction I've never encountered the requirement (or need) to do so. I'll wait for those with more technical knowledge of EPS to weigh in.

Answer (score 1):

You should be safe to leave a gap of ~3/16", based on the coefficient of thermal expansion in the table here (https://insulationcorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ICA-LITE_Spec_Sheet.pdf). With a value of 35x10e-6in/in per deg F, assuming a 100deg maximum temperature delta x 48" wide piece-> 0.000035*100*48=0.168". This would assume 100deg from your install temperature I believe... so 1/8" may be more appropriate @30deg (F).

You should look-up and find your particular mfr/model spec sheet to find a similar table for the product you plan to install, and perform the calculation for it.